# How to talk about T-posing

Tags: verbs, english-to-japanese, neologism

If I wanted to say something like,

Whenever I play such-and-such game, the characters always end T-posing.

> 〇〇ゲームをすると、キャラクターはいつもTポーズになってしまいます。

Or is this said a different way?

Is there more than one acceptable verb or expression to describe 3D characters doing a T-pose?

Comment: T字ポーズ may be less confusing. I just found this was a net meme, but it has never been popular in Japan. Although the literal meaning of T(字)ポーズ is almost self-evident, if you're trying to say something with that meme in mind, it's unlikely that Japanese gamers will understand. (To be honest, I don't even understand whether your sentence is a joke or not...)

Comment: The sentence wasn't meant to be a joke. It was meant to describe a game's buggy behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I was overthinking then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Japanese use “T-pose” as well to explain like that situation. But this bug is not popular in Japan. So when you tell Japanese native speaker about it, they would be confused.